# libudev error while configuring cgminer on fedora 22

Tags: cgminer, antminer

I am using Fedora 22, 32bit OS and have Antminer U3 for mining operations

got the cgminer source code from GIT:
git clone https://github.com/bitmaintech/cgminer

while running **./configure --enable-icarus** the command ends up in error as below

```
./configure: line 11972: -pthread: command not found
checking libudev.h usability... no
checking libudev.h presence... no
checking for libudev.h... no
configure: error: "udev support requested but libudev not installed"
configure: error: ./configure failed for compat/libusb-1.0
```

I tried using system libusb, but no success

**./configure --enable-icarus --with-system-libusb**

```
checking for pthread_create in -lpthread... yes
checking for library containing addstr... no
configure: WARNING: Could not find curses library - if you want a TUI, install libncurses-dev or pdcurses-dev
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for LIBUSB... no
configure: error: Could not find usb library - please install libusb-1.0
```

libusb is part of systemd package and my system has latest installed.
checked from

```
sudo dnf upgrade systemd
```

command returned *Nothing to do.*

Could you please help where i could be going wrong in setting up CGMiner ?

PS: I tried bfgminer, but ended up in errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get cgminer to build the icarus extension on a fresh CentOS system like so:

```
yum install git
git clone https://github.com/bitmaintech/cgminer
cd cgminer/
yum install -y autoconf make automake gcc gcc-c++ kernel-devel libcurl libcurl-devel
yum install libudev-devel
./autogen.sh
./configure --enable-icarus
make
./cgminer
```

So I think you're missing the package `libudev-devel`. (It might be named something different on Fedora 22 - I don't know.)

Comment: That worked like charm. There were 2 packages missing kernel-devel and libudev-devel. after they were installed the ./configure --enable-icarus worked fine. Thanks Nick